# SQL - how to query where a column is an array and you want to get records where the element is in the array

Tags: sql, google-cloud-spanner

In Google Spanner how can I create a query with a `WHERE` clause about a column, `FOO` that is of type `ARRAY<STRING>` where the column, `FOO` array contains the value `[ "BAR" ]`?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to do this.
But as you same mentioned. You can use UNNEST method into an struct array type data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ("BAR") IN UNNEST (FOO).
```

If you want to use as subquery could be:

```
SELECT ARRAY( SELECT * FROM UNNEST(FOO) AS x where x = "BAR")
```

You can find more details for working with arrays in cloud spanner here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out shortly after:
`SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ( "BAR" ) IN UNNEST (FOO);`